# JQuery Datepicker: If selected date is today's date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am able to determine if the selected date is in the past by using:

```
var due_date = $('#due_date').val();
if(new Date(due_date).getTime() <  new Date().getTime())
{
  //do stuff
}
```

^This works fine

I am using the following to determine if a selected date is today's date:

```
var due_date = $('#due_date').val();
var today = new Date().getTime();
if(new Date(due_date).getTime() == today)
{
    alert('ok');
}
```

But it's not hitting that alert.  What is wrong with the above statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string "30/03/2012" when used to create a date results in a Date object that represents midnight on the 30 March 2012. When you call `new Date()` it creates a Date object that represents the current time (including seconds and milliseconds).

You'll need to set the hour, minute, second and millisecond properties of your Date object to 0 so that they represent the exact same time, using the `setHours()`, `setMinutes()`, etc functions.

For more information about the Date object take a look at the [MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 12):

The datepicker object has a getDate method you can use that returns a date value to compare it to a new date().  You do have to some further massaging on the new date, but this should get you what you want.

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aztechy/LEzmH/)

HTML:

```
Date: <input type="text" id="thedate"/>
<div id="checkDate">Check Date</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#thedate').datepicker();

$('#checkDate').bind('click', function() {
  var selectedDate = $('#thedate').datepicker('getDate');
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0);
  today.setMinutes(0);
  today.setSeconds(0);
  if (Date.parse(today) == Date.parse(selectedDate)) {
    alert('today!');
  } else {
    alert('not today');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you're comparing apples to apples. Here's an easy way to check:

jQuery:

```
$('#dp').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()).getTime();
        var selected = new Date(dateText).getTime();
        if (today > selected) alert('prior to today');
        else if (today < selected) alert('after today');
        else alert('today');
    }
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yBDVJ/)**.

Comment: hi, i have used https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ date picker and i need to check the selected date is today or not. i used your code but its not showing either answer nor datepicker

Answer (score 0):

`getTime()` returns milliseconds, instead compare the day month and year, which I believe a normal date comparison does(maybe wrong). See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Answer (score -1):

also you can do it like this:

```
$( function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
        { dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: 0, 
        //maxDate: "+12M +10D"   
        }
      );
    } );
```

with  minDate: 0,  you are able to display the current days ahead,