# comparing date value in inputbox using if else in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code below is in javascript, $('#date_start').change(function(){ is working fine, but when im using if else statement to compare the date inputted in my inputbox from the current date, nothing happens at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#date_start').change(function(){

var startdate = $('#date_start').datepicker("getDate");
var today = new Date();  
var tomorrow = today.add(2).day();
if(startdate.getTime() < today.getTime()){
    document.getElementById('finish').disabled = true;
}
else{
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle ? or working code snippet ?

Comment: What kind of date format are you getting from date picker ?

Comment: Please provide output getting from var startdate

Comment: console.log(startdate.getTime()); and console.log(today.getTime()); and check whether the format is correct or not??

Comment: You need to make sure both dates are in same format. Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946232/jquery-datepicker-if-selected-date-is-todays-date

Answer (score 0):

Remove Time from both of Date and compare it.

```
String input = "2012/01/20 12:05:10.321";
DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = inputFormatter.parse(input);

DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String output = outputFormatter.format(date);
```